# Which class is preferred for android authentication and achievements in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Which class is preferred for android authentication and achievements in Unity, PlayGamesPlatform or Social? 
I mean that PlayGamesPlatform is used in in any case for

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

but then i can do

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(SignInCallback, false);//auth
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(
               GPGSIds.achievement_git_gud, //achievment code
               1,//increment size
               (bool success) => {
                   callback
               });
```

or

```
 Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {//auth
 //auth callback
 };
 Social.ReportProgress(
              GPGSIds.achievement_git_gud, //achievment code     
              1,           
              (bool success) => {
                    // handle success or failure
              });
 });
```

**So which class should i prefer?**

Comment: If I were developing a game I'd probably go with the one that says "Games" in the class definition...

Comment: Brandon, totally agree, but problem that Social is unity native class, and PlayGamesPlatform is a plugin-asset

Comment: That makes more sense. With that said, I would go with the one that Unity provides since it is most likely updated more often. It looks like PlayGamesPlatform was released as a plugin before Social was available. It also seems like Social is a more platform-independent approach. Although, if you require more android-specific functionality it looks like they can both be used together.

Comment: @qwnick if you are ever planning on releasing your game for iOS I would suggest using social, if you take a quick look at the google play services for iOS it says it is deprecated, and not likely to work as expected: https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/achievements

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, i understand now that i should use native Social, can one of you move comment to answer please, so that I can choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the one that Unity provides since it is most likely updated more often. It looks like PlayGamesPlatform was released as a plugin before Social was available. It also seems like Social is a more platform-independent approach. Although, if you require more android-specific functionality it looks like they can both be used together. - Answer from comments.